# Error downloading mail attachments with apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, email-attachments

I'm working in an apache camel project that download any attachment in the inbox, to achieve that I followed the information in the Consuming mails with attachment sample from http://camel.apache.org/mail.html. That works pretty well except when the attachment has a filename with special characters or spaces. For example if the attachment has a filename like "***voucher.pdf***" the program works and downloads the file, but if it has a filename like "***Pase de abordar en línea (1).pdf***" I get this error:

> Message History
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor
>   Elapsed (ms) [route1            ] [route1            ]
>   [imaps://imap.gmail.com:993?consumer.delay=60000&contentType=multipart%2FMIXED&]
>   [      2576] [route1            ] [convertBodyTo1    ]
>   [convertBodyTo[java.lang.String]
>   ] [       642] [route1            ] [process1          ]
>   [Processor@0x13e344d
>   ] [      1903] [route1            ] [to1               ]
>   [file:C:/outputFolder/?flatten=true&fileName=${header.nombref}
>   ] [         8]
>
> Stacktrace
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException:
>   Cannot store file:
>   C:\outputFolder\=?UTF-8?Q?Pase_de_abordar_en_l=C3=ADnea_(1).pdf?=     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.processExchange(MailConsumer.java:392)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.processBatch(MailConsumer.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\outputFolder\=?UTF-8?Q?Pase_de_abordar_en_l=C3=ADnea_(1).pdf?= (El
>   nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la
>   etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:162)    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.prepareOutputFileChannel(FileOperations.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByStream(FileOperations.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:326)
>     ... 24 more 7209 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 -
>   imaps://imap.gmail.com:993] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline 
>   - Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline for exchange: Exchange[ID-desarrollo01-59804-1524233458774-0-2] Exception:
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException:
>   Cannot store file:
>   C:\outputFolder\=?UTF-8?Q?Pase_de_abordar_en_l=C3=ADnea_(1).pdf?= 7209
>   [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - imaps://imap.gmail.com:993] WARN
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer  - Exchange failed, so
>   rolling back message status:
>   Exchange[ID-desarrollo01-59804-1524233458774-0-2]
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException:
>   Cannot store file:
>   C:\outputFolder\=?UTF-8?Q?Pase_de_abordar_en_l=C3=ADnea_(1).pdf?=     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.processExchange(MailConsumer.java:392)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.processBatch(MailConsumer.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\outputFolder\=?UTF-8?Q?Pase_de_abordar_en_l=C3=ADnea_(1).pdf?= (El
>   nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la
>   etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:162)    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.prepareOutputFileChannel(FileOperations.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.writeFileByStream(FileOperations.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:326)
>     ... 24 more

This is my main method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        ksp.setResource("C://Program Files (x86)//Java//jre1.8.0_161//lib//security");
        ksp.setPassword("changeit");

        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
        kmp.setKeyPassword("changeit");

        SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
        scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);        


        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        RutaMail routeBuilder = new RutaMail();

        SimpleRegistry jndi= new SimpleRegistry();
        jndi.put("keystore", scp);              

        CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(jndi);





        try {

            ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
            ctx.start();
            Thread.sleep(30000);
            ctx.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the camel route:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("imaps://imap.gmail.com:993?username=user@gmail.com&password=password"
                + "&delete=false&unseen=true&consumer.delay=60000&contentType=multipart/MIXED")
                        .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
                        .process(new MailProcessor())

                        .to("file:C:/outputFolder/?flatten=true&fileName=${header.nombref}")
                        .log("el nombre del archivo es  ${header.nombref}").end();
    }

}
```

This is the processor:

```
public class MailProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String nombre="";


        // the API is a bit clunky so we need to loop
        Map<String, DataHandler> attachments = exchange.getIn().getAttachments();

        String file="";

        if (attachments.size() > 0) {
            for (String name : attachments.keySet()) {                


                DataHandler dh = attachments.get(name);

                String filename =dh.getName();
                nombre =filename;


                byte[] data = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter()
                                  .convertTo(byte[].class, dh.getInputStream());                                             

                exchange.getIn().setBody( data);
                exchange.getIn().setHeader("nombref", filename);
            }          


        }
   }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure that the user has permission to write to the directory

Comment: What version of Camel do you use. And have you tried with a newer version.

Comment: _"Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\outputFolder\=?UTF-8?Q?Pase_de_abordar_en_l=C3=ADnea_(1).pdf?= (El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos)"_ suggests you (or maybe JavaMail) didn't properly decode the filename before using it.

Comment: Hi, @SheetalMohanSharma the user has permission, the code works well if the filename doesn't have special characters in it.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I'm using version 2.18.1.redhat-000015,I haven't try any other vesion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your OS doesn't allow to save file with such name.

Comment: I don't know about that, If I download the file manually from the mail there is no problem. I'm using windows and the OS allows that kind of 
 file names.

Comment: Try to set file name into the header CamelFileName instead "nombref" into MailProcessor and use simple .to("file://C:/outputFolder") without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the 'file' component incorrectly. You need to add // after URI name. Try with file://C:/outputFolder/?flatten=true&fileName=${header.nombref
and let me know.

Comment: Also please check which OS you are using. Is it Windows or Linux. I believe the file path you are setting is for a windows box.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but I'm still getting the same error. My OS is Windows by the way.

Comment: ?UTF-8?Q?Pase_de_abordar_en_l=C3=ADnea_(1).pdf?=

what is this '?' mark doing here in file name. I don't think windows allows ? in file name

Comment: That's the thing, the filename is "Pase de abordar en línea (1).pdf", I don't know why camel put those "?" marks

Comment: might be there are some special characters. but using utf-8 encoding should not create problem. 
Can you log the URI getting prepared for your route when message is sent to the camel file component. I think there is some problem with header.nombref in your message.